# How to dynamically copy the text between a particular tag from a website whenever it is loaded/opened

Tags: html, tags, jsp-tags, htmltext

Is there any way to get the text between a particular tag (say < p>....< /p>) for a website ?

**Complete Scenario**
Suppose I visit a website xyz.com. Now I want for every index page of the site
(e.g. xyz.com/abc,xyz.com/a/b etc)
 that I visit , the text between < p>...< /p> tag or n'th < p>..< /p> tag to be copied in some text file for offline reading/studying or for hard copy.

Comment: I want the auto selection of the text between the para tag and only visiting the webpage should work....i.e., the text should be automatically selected and copied/appended to some text file(say MS Word)

Answer (score 0):

I use Evernote Clipper for this purpose.
First install Evernote. It is a software to keep notes (40 million plus users). I personally think this software is awesome and use it extensively.
Then get the browser extension Evernote Clipper. I use chrome. I am not sure the browser that you have would have that extension so check on that.
With evernote clipper you can either select an area on the webpage to clip it. Or you can select the whole page.
Once clipped, it will sync to the evernote that you installed in the first step.
After that the notes will be available to you even if you go offline.

I know it almost sounds like an advertisement for evernote but I am really not affiliated with the company.
I am just a user and love this software. So far the free version of this software has everything that I need so haven't purchased the premium version. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks Vishal ! But I want the auto selection of the text and automatically to be appended to some text file. I just added this as a comment to my question.

Comment: Aah.. well that calls for writing a browser plugin by yourself or getting someone to do it for you. Really doubtful if there is a tool already there for such a specific use case.

Comment: Thanks Vishal for your suggestion but how if it can be done using Java interacting with web-browser.....First getting the html and then the text between the desired tags, all dynamic !!!!