# Get URL from active browser (or active tab of browser) using core java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, google-chrome, browser

I found many similar questions on stackoverflow but not the one working for me.

How can I get the url of active tab of browser using **core java** (by using process name, port, or any method....).
My purpose is to parse the html content of the active browser/tab.

This is not a duplicate as I couldn't find the one based on core java.

Comment: Is this for browser based testing? Why not use Selenium?

Comment: There's no way to do this generically, which is why you'd typically want to use a test framework to abstract away the per-browser differences.

Comment: No, It's not for browser based testing, I want to get the html of the webpage by url, so that I could get the text between desired tags....  For reference please see my another post   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656276/how-to-dynamically-copy-the-text-between-a-particular-tag-from-a-website-wheneve/17656504?noredirect=1#comment25723325_17656504)

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: @Sahan no and even I don't remember exactly whether I switched to some other activity after that or found any workaround :( It's being a long time :)

Comment: Me either. Anyway thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the URL of active tab.
However you can create the Tab with particular URL.
You can also add TCP-IP monitors in eclipse to check the communication with the particular URL.